# Android SQLite Asset Helper error

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

So I am attempting to use the Android SQLite Asset Helper to pre-package a database with my application and I have run into an issue.  Here's a little bit of information to get started:

- Using Android Studio (gradle)
- I have modified build.grade to include
  `compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'`
- I have my database zipped (workoutsDatabase.sqlite.zip) in my src/main/assets/databases folder
- my WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.java looks as follows (sorry for the bad formatting, the formatter is being stupid this morning!)

  ```
  import android.content.Context;

  import android.database.Cursor;

  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;


  import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

  public class WorkoutsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
  ```

  // All Static variables
      // Database Version
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  ```
  // Database Name
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "workoutsDatabase.sqlite";



  public WorkoutsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
  ```

Can anyone see why this might be thinking that a .jar file is a zip? and also, is there anything else I am missing to get this working properly?

Here is the error:

```
Error:: error reading /Users/rdeckert/AndroidStudioProjects/MyPR/app/libs/android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar; cannot read zip file
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/dx --dex --output /Users/rdeckert/AndroidStudioProjects/MyPR/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/android-sqlite-asset-helper-295afb1e2c04cd27e606e7f0ffde55bd32716c79.jar /Users/rdeckert/AndroidStudioProjects/MyPR/app/libs/android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:128)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
    1 error; aborting
```

I tried updating the Zip file (database) and that didnt do anything.

Comment: I guess name of your zip file should be workoutsDatabase.zip instead of workoutsDatabase.sqlite.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I removed compile `'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'` from the build.gradle it compiled and worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but once i also removed this line but this didnt help me, So what you need to do is:

Method 1: Try to clean your project in 'Build' Option.

Method 2: Clean and Rerun your project in 'RUN' Option.

Method 3: If above method didnt help you then restart you android Studio.

Medthod 4: Restart Your PC, this will surely removed the error.

Comment: Restart PC is only needed if ADB is working incorrectly. Sometimes it can be useful to delete `build` directories manually (using Explorer/Finder).

Comment: Martin.. I did it by doing restart my pc. Dats why i suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
```